# Apologies re image links update => bumping

Tags: discussion, images, bumping, minor-edits

In the days before StackExchange used **i.stack.imgur.com** for images, I had linked quite a few images to my college's web server. Now all those links are broken, and I will eventually move them to **i.stack.imgur.com**. But the consequence is: the old posts get bumped to the frontpage. To turn this post into a question:

> ***Q***. Is there a way to edit a post without bumping it to the frontpage?

---

***Update*** (*22Sep2017*):

> 12Mar2017: "Will work on them incrementally."

I believe I have now updated all the lost images and broken links in my postings
(triggered by an email/username change from **orourke** to **jorourke**)—approximately 200 postings.
I appreciate everyone's tolerance during this six-month process.
Thanks especially to @MartinSleziak for retagging.

Comment: This would be a method that all the spammers would like to find.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: If everybody can do this, then yes. -- But I doubt this would be the case if it were a privilege earned at some decent number of points (3k?, 5k?, 10k?).

Comment: @Stefan: If you have uncountably many points, then yes. Namely, you need to have database editing access.

Comment: Joseph, what ballpark figure are we talking about? If it's really a lot of posts, maybe you can make a specific request for this to be automated if possible?

Comment: BTW the possibility of minor edits without bumping has been discussed previously. For example, [Minor edits, subject to review](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/192) or [“Silent” Edits for MO?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/784). (I would expect most of these past discussions to be tagged ([meta-tag:bumping]) and/or ([meta-tag:minor-edits]), but it seems that it is not the case.)

Comment: I will specifically point out  this post, which is basically question whether there is some consensus when bumping too many questions is considered *excessive*: [Do we have an unofficial quota on how many old questions one should bump for minor edits in a single day?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/599)

Comment: @AsafKaragila If searching for [jpg url:cs.smith.edu](http://mathoverflow.net/search?q=jpg+url%3Acs.smith.edu) can be considered as a rough estimate, this search returns about 100 posts.
Of course, there might be many other domains with broken links (be it images or regular links) - one example is mentioned [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2017/3/12).

Comment: It seems that the Community user sometimes performs minor edits without bumping the post -- see e.g. [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/237374/lattice-n-gons-with-ordered-side-lengths-1-2-3-n/237741#237741) -- the Community user edited the answer 2 days ago, but the last activity of the thread was 9 months ago. -- Or do I misinterpret what happened there?

Comment: @StefanKohl That appears to be part of [SE's move towards https](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058), and would have been initiated by someone with database access (likely running some sort of script to go through all posts and alter `http://` links to `https://`).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, Martin is correct---about 100 images. Will work on them incrementally.

Comment: If it's about questions you have asked yourself, I am pretty sure that nobody will yell at you for bumping them... your questions are often so creative and invite to think out-of-the-box !

Comment: May I add that many of them deserve review?  Of course prioritize your work as you see fit Joseph, but if there are groups with a common theme, including some unanswered questions, I would be pleased to see each group once again on the front page occasionally.  Gerhard "Votes For An O'Rourke Channel" Paseman, 2017.03.12.

Comment: Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Does anyone know the date when StackExchange introduced using **...imgur...** for posted images?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke As far as I can say, August 2010: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/ and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/please-allow-image-uploads-directly-onto-the-site/60782#60782 (But I guess for MO this is relevant only since the site joined SE network.)

Comment: I have noticed that several of your posts have ([tag:geometry]) tag, which is deprecated [according to the tag-info](http://mathoverflow.net/tags/geometry/info). So if the posts are going to be bumped anyway, it might be a good opportunity to remove the tag at the same time.

Comment: First of all, I look forward to see Joe's posting being bumped to the front page and updating the beautiful pictures is a great opportunity for that. Second, I noticed that having English mistakes and other forms of sloppiness  has the effect of having my posting bumped (when I or other edit to correct these mistakes.) In a sense, this is averaged away with the clear disadvantages of sloppiness and mistakes. (And the sense of unjust bumping also give me an intensive to be less sloppy.) It is a little similar to being short which is overall a disadvantage but good on flights.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to Joseph O'Rourke's question, but rather an apology of my own, along the same lines: Many of my old posts used images that I hosted at Photobucket, and they have now have disallowed direct linking for free accounts. Thus I have now begun moving all the images to imgur as well.

I will try to restrict myself to bumping 4 or 5 old answers to the front page per day. As my photobucket album had 64 images in it, this process should be finished within 2 weeks or so.

Comment: I guess this post could be considered as an answer to the title of this question, if one were to interpret it as _a request for apologies_ :)

Comment: Why don't you just do them all in one go, if they anway need to be fixed? -- Is having once 64 posts bumped more of a nuisance than having 14 times 4 or 5 posts bumped?

Comment: @StefanKohl I was intending to (roughly) follow the guideline in this post https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/604 .

Comment: I'm still working on mine, a few per day. Kinda fun to revisit these old posts (and sometimes embarrassing).

Comment: @Stefan, yes, having 64 (which is all or nearly all) the current questions bumped off or nearly off the current list is more of a nuisance to readers.  I suppose four or five happening every twelve hours is still acceptable.  Gerhard "Maybe More During Slow Periods" Paseman, 2017.07.26

Comment: This is now done.  As it turns out, many of my posts had multiple images, so there were a lot fewer than 64 bumped posts (closer to 20).