# latex.mathoverflow.net/png images broken

Tags: support, status-completed, images

Prior to MathJax and jsmath, MathOverflow used http://latex.mathoverflow.net/png to generate images of mathematical equations to insert in posts (e.g. [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4132/what-function-has-fourier-series-the-harmonic-series#question)). That didn't last very long but all of those image links are currently broken.

Comment: Could it be a good occassion to instead of fixing this get rid of it? How many question should there be that might be affected (I have no idea how long this was used)? This seems even somewhat more feasible in view of the fact that the posts are not turned unreadble.

Comment: Sure thing. Go ahead!

Comment: Is there any way for moderators to "edit" the comments that need to be LaTeX-ified, or to replace them with latexified copies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the questions provided by m0sa (thank you!), that would contain the type of "LaTeX" that creates problems. (Please note that at the moment it works, so the post does not look broken, but looking at the source it will be clear that this is done different from how it is done now.)

Everybody who is in an editing-mood can pick a post here and add MathJax. After having completed it, please strike-out the post (rather than delete) from this list.

As Andrew Stacey said let us try not to make too many at once. (The revision history of this question could serve as a guide to know how many were done in the recent past.) <strike>At the bottom there are three comments where moderator powers wouls be needed. (I also put the corresponding questions there to minimize bumps.)</strike>

**Still to do:**

> ## ***All done***

**Completed:**

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4516</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4473</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4615</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4625</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4658</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4601</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4494</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4664</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/5161</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/5321</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/5338</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4429</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4083</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4115</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4121</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4125</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4128</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4130</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4135</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4169</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4174</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4180</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4193</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4233</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4246</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4268</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4276</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4296</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4333</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4406</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4409</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4422</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4424</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4452</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4456</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4459</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4460</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4672</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4674</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4709</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4728</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4779</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4851</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4865</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4939</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4966</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/5006</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/5008</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/5013</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/5044</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/5064</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/5103</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/5122</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/5144</strike>

---

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/1845#comment-6101</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4180#comment-4382</strike>

<strike>http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/4429#comment-4719</strike>

Comment: (I only accepted to improve visibility.)

Comment: Couple of lessons from doing a couple of these: there may be more than one part of the post that needs fixing (ie check the answers too, and take the opportunity to fix minor things in those since the whole thing will be bumped anyway); and the "alt" text may not fully correspond to what is in the image.

Comment: Oh, and not all of these questions are questions.  Some are answers.  So if fixing more than one issue in a question-and-answer list, it will be that the answer should also be struck out (if you can locate it in the list).

Comment: Thanks to everybody who contributed so far, and especially to @AndrewStacey for the remarks. I was aware of the answer-issue but did not know the potential "alt" text problem. In any case, once this is completed/close to completion I will double-check the changes.

Answer (score 9):

Upon discovering that the question linked in this question was mine, I decided to fix it and discovered also that a simple regexp would not suffice.  Sometimes it should have been displayed maths, sometimes not, and there were sufficient other small changes that I felt it needed a person to do.  For example, not every mathematical phrase in that series of questions and answers was sent off to `latex.mathoverflow.net`, and I'd used the `\sb` command to get round the dodgy parsing of underscores (seems this isn't supported by MathJaX).

Is the list of questions using `latex.mathoverflow.net` very long?  Maybe you could post the links and then kind hearted users could (slowly!) go through them and fix them.  Say, no more than 5 a day to avoid flooding the active tab?

Comment: It seems a bit stupid that you work a lot with this and then get get a downvote as a result...

Comment: @AndrásBátkai I found that highly amusing.  But it did make me realise that when editing old posts it is probably a good idea to state that this post is ancient history and so voting on it *just because it is on the active list* is a bit pointless.

Comment: I tried to search for latex.mathoverflow.net on the site in order to identify posts for manual fixing, however this seems to fail both with the search on the page as well as  with Google; presumably one would have to search the database or a dump. Now, likely I could somehow manage to do this, but I never did, while I have the impression some do this all the time, so I will wait for a while if such a list is created by somebody who can do this more easily then me before venturing to create it myself.

Comment: @quid Yes, it would be easiest from the database dumps as the *text* `latex.mathoverflow.net` doesn't appear on the pages but only in the page source.

Comment: see my answer http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/374/latex-mathoverflow-net-png-images-broken#answer-382

Answer (score 9):

I ran a quick query, here are the non deleted posts and comments containing `latex.mathoverflow.net/png` in CSV format: http://pastebin.com/2ffiacNF

Answer (score 3):

I propose we ask the Stack Exchange team if they can do a search and replace on the database for us.

As an example, we want to replace

```
![\sum\sb {n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n} \cos(n \pi t)](http://latex.mathoverflow.net/png?%5Csum%5F%7Bn%20%5Cge%201%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%20%5Ccos%28n%20%5Cpi%20t%29)
```

with

```
$\sum\sb {n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n} \cos(n \pi t)$
```

It's probably a reasonable thing to do with a regular expression!

Comment: Would not be better to have displaystyle here?

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, I got the script that produces the images running again. I don't think this is a good solution, short term or long term.