# Appropriate procedure for removing little used tags which are too specific

Tags: discussion, support, tags

What is the correct procedure for removing tags which only have a single question, and would be better off with a less specific tag?

My example is a question which was tagged 'relative-entropy'. Since 'relative-entropy' was too specific and only had that one question, I retagged the question with 'entropy'. Was this the correct course of action? Or should I have used a tag synonym instead?

By the way, how does one go about deleting the tag 'relative-entropy' which is now vacant?

Comment: Vacant tags are automatically deleted after a few hours.

Comment: @François: Thanks a lot! That is good to know.

Comment: In my opinion, for a uniquely used tag, just retag as you did. To add to vacant tags are autodelted: to give 'better' tags to q with a 'uniquely used' tag seems now even more important as also *uniquely used* tags get autodeleted (after 6 month). So if the uniquely used tag is around since a while not retagging it would soon leave the question with [tag:untagged] I don't yet fully understand synonyms but I am under the impression they are rather for common things so rather not for this situation (to avoid recurring issues with different terminology and a like).

Comment: Just to add more information about tag pruning: Empty tags are removed once [in 24 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags). If a tag has only 1 question [after 6 months](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418), it will also be deleted.

Comment: Just to update the information from the preceding comment. Now a tag with single question are not remove [if it has a tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki).