# Editing an old post to add MathJax

Tags: discussion, mathjax, editing, bumping

Sometimes I come across an old post which does not use MathJax. Is it OK to edit such a post if the edit improves readability?

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2890/cohomology-and-eilenberg-maclane-spaces) (and its answers) motivated this post. I know some users aren't fond of bumping old questions, so I thought I'd check.

Comment: I think it's fine to do so.

Comment: Limit yourself to reviving at most 5 dormant posts per day.

Comment: Rather similar older discussion: [What's our consensus on people resurrecting old questions just to edit formatting?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/169). BTW I think that ([meta-tag:bumping]) would be an appropriate tag for both of them (but I don't have enough reputation to edit on meta). I am not sure whether it adds anything relevant, but I will also add link to [this conversation in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/conversation/editing-titles-and-editing-old-posts).

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: Sure. I wasn't planning to go looking for posts.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Done and done.

Comment: It depends whether the LaTeX is warranted. Editing to put `$ $` around a variable is not really that important. But posts where the user used _no_ LaTeX formatting and extensive pseudo-TeX clearly can benefit in terms of readability with the edit.